# What are the number of solutions of $x+y+z=r$ .By just giving the solutions as even/odd pairs?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

In Detail:- I want to know that if I **just consider odd/even** then $x+y+z =r$ which having solutions $= (n+r-1)C(r-1)$ . But when  we classify the numbers as just odd and even then there will be reduced solutions

**Example** **$x+y=2$** will have the pairs (considering $x,y>=0$) **$\{(2,0),(0,2),(1,1)\}$** but when classified on odd/even basis , the solutions become **{(Even,Even),(Even,Even),(odd,odd)}** respectively and the reduced solutions will be **{(even,even),(odd,odd)}**

Can we arrive to some general formula ? Please Explain !

Comment: If $r$ is odd there will be $4$ possibilities (all odd, or the three different one odd and two even). If $r$ is even there will again be $4$ possibilities (all even or the three different one even and two odd). There is a natural generalization to $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_k=r$, in which case there are $2^{k-1}$ possibilities for any $r$.  But I am not sure whether this is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your formula , if $k=3$ and $r=1$ then we get the pairs as          $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ which when generalised as odd/even pairs we get $3$ solutions $\{(O,E,E),(E,O,E),(E,E,O)\}$ which are distinct so all can be counted . This is not satisfying $2^{k-1}$.
Can You please help in more generalization? 
Here O-odd and E-even.